# how to set errorprovider icon left the control?

Tags: errorprovider

I want, set "*error provider*" icon left the *text box* or *combo box* ?!
I tried this code. But the feature that wrong!

> errorProvider1.GetIconAlignment(errorProvider1,ErrorIconAlignment.MiddleLeft);
>   errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1 , "Can't Empty");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without that code was set.
In the "error Provider" properties, Using the " Right To Left " property.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that that Hadi's original code did not work is because the first parameter to the errorProvider1.SetIconAlignment method was incorrect.  The first parameter should be the control to which the error applies, not the error provider itself.  Thus, the following works:

`errorProvider1.SetIconAlignment(textBox1, ErrorIconAlignment.MiddleLeft);
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Can't Empty");`

This might be a better solution than using the ErrorProvider RightToLeft property because it permits setting the icon position on a per control basis.

Comment: One thing to realize is if you call errorProvider1.Clear(), the icon alignment also reverts back to the default. So the icon alignment should be set prior to each call to SetError